# Как убрать мерцание картинки при её изменении на объекте в tkinter? (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть Label, на котором есть картинка. Когда я меняю картинку на этом Label на другую, старая картинка убирается, а потом появляется новая. Между этими событиями я вижу пустое окно, т.е. происходит мерцание экрана при изменении картинки. Как это исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
import time,threading

folder = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\\"

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
image = PhotoImage(file=folder+'frame1.png')
lab = Label(root, image=image)
lab.place(x=130)

def loop(lab):
    while True:
        image = PhotoImage(file=folder+'frame1.png')
        lab.config(image=image)
        image = PhotoImage(file=folder+'frame2.png')
        lab.config(image=image)

potok_1 = threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(lab,))
potok_1.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Смотрите ответ здесь <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307718/python-tkinter-display-images-on-canvas-it-always-blink>. И про потоки в ткинтер здесь < https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+event+loop>

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Жаль, что комментарий нельзя пометить как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Помог [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414930/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-tkinter-python#comment2518195_1414930):

> Смотрите ответ здесь [python Tkinter Display images on canvas, it always blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307718/python-tkinter-display-images-on-canvas-it-always-blink).
> И про потоки в ткинтер здесь [Tcl event loop](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+event+loop) – Сергей Кох

Чтобы убрать мерцание, нужно загрузить изображение следующим образом:

```
img = Image.open("my_image.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label.config(image=photo) # Установка загруженного изображения
container.obr = photo
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)